# double series with positive term

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_{ij}\ge0\,\forall i,j$ , $(c_k)$ is a enumeration of $\{a_{ij}\}$ , prove the following are equivalent:

1) $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}=B$$
2) $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k =C$$

In this case B = C.

I think that this is a application of 'rearrangements of absolutely convergent series converge to the same limit' , but I am not sure how to present the details of the proof,

e.g. Do I need to prove that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a'_i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}$ where $(a'_i)$ is a enumeration of $a_{ij}$ s.t. $(a'_1,a'_2,...) = (a_{11},a_{12},...,a_{21},...,a_{31},...)$ ? (well, is this statement problematic at all?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute convergence is enough. Let $c_k$ be any enumeration of $a_{ij}$, then let $\phi : \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$  be the $1-1$ map such that $a_{ij} = c_{\phi(i,j)}$ (we don't know what $\phi$ is, but we don't care as well). Now,
\begin{align}
 & \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij} = B  \iff \displaystyle\sum_{i,j \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}} a_{ij} = B \ (\text{absolute convergence allows combination of sum}) \\ & \iff \displaystyle\sum_{(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}} a_{\phi(i,j)} = B \ (\text{absolute convergence allows rearrangement}) \\& \iff \displaystyle\sum_{k=\phi(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}} c_k = B \ (\text{change of index}) 
\end{align}

We are done.

Comment: I am confused with how grouping and rearranging terms apply to the case of grouping infinitely many terms (e.g. the first step in your answer) , in fact I don't 'understand' how those $a_{ij}$ can 'line up' s.t. we can glue the $a_{2j}$ after $a_{1j}$. What is the 'position' of $a_{21}$ ? If it is a finite number, then there are only finitely many terms before it, contradicting the fact that $a_{1j}$ is in front of them.

I know it can be defined by bijection, but I just can't 'understand' it....well, intuitively? It's kind of violating my intuition.

Comment: I understand, because I had the same problem, how do you make them 'line up'. Well, it violates intuition completely, and there are many things in mathematics that do. I actually wrote the first step in a leap of faith before verifying it carefully with my classmates (and they are far ahead of me in these kind of things). I can't quite say anything, except that the bijections that are referred to here carry, in some sense, their own intuitions with them. I'm frankly quite embarrassed, and apologize at my lack of explanation, but that's just the way things are sometimes in math:odd.